# How to manipulate GeoJson data from opendatafrance using typescript?

Tags: typescript, nestjs, geojson

I am using nestjs and an interceptor to geolocalize an adress with opendatafrance:

**geoloc.interceptor.ts**:

```
import { GeoJsonGeometryTypes } from 'geojson';
import { Observable, from, lastValueFrom } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Warehouse } from 'src/features/warehouse/entities/warehouse.entity';
import { Point } from 'typeorm';
var NodeGeocoder = require('node-geocoder');

var options = {
  provider: "opendatafrance",
};

var geometry: Point;

var geocoder = NodeGeocoder(options);
@Injectable()
export class geoLocInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  async intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Promise<Observable<any>> {

    var monaddress = context.switchToHttp().getRequest().body.address;
    const geocodeResult = from(geocoder.geocode(monaddress));
    const geocoded = await lastValueFrom(geocodeResult);
  context.switchToHttp().getRequest().body = {
    address: context.switchToHttp().getRequest().body.address,
    geometry: geocoded,
    warehouseName: context.switchToHttp().getRequest().body.warehouseName,
    isActive: context.switchToHttp().getRequest().body.isActive,
    companyId: context.switchToHttp().getRequest().body.companyId
}
    return next.handle().pipe(
       map(value => {
        return {
          ...value,
          geoCoder: geocoded
        }
      })
      )
  }

}
```

I am receiving this:

```
[
  {
    latitude: 43.401061,
    longitude: -0.565407,
    state: "64, Pyrénées-Atlantiques, Nouvelle-Aquitaine",
    city: "Artix",
    zipcode: "64170",
    citycode: "64061",
    countryCode: "FR",
    country: "France",
    type: "housenumber",
    id: "64061_0625_00180",
    streetName: "Avenue De Serres Ste Marie",
    streetNumber: "180",
    provider: "opendatafrance",
  },
]
```

What I can see is that there are a lot of more information like shown in the below screenshot:
[image]

There is for instance raw/features/geometry/ I would like to access to.

My problem in my code is that I have an entity with the folloging code:

```
 ...
    @Column("geometry")
    point: Point
...
```

So I want to assing a Point to this value in:

```
context.switchToHttp().getRequest().body = {
   ...
    geometry: geocoded,
    ...
}
```

It seems impossible to get the raw part of the GeoJson provided by **opendatafrance** and I am getting an error like:

```
[Nest] 39912  - 01/09/2023 18:18:02   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] unknown GeoJSON type
QueryFailedError: unknown GeoJSON type
```

If I look at the debugger watch I can see the raw record:
[image]

If I modify the variable according to the debugger watch it does not work neither:
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards,